# Question about Vector sapces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Property of an operator in a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258270/property-of-an-operator-in-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-v-over-r)

How do we prove the stabilization property：there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have $K_n=K_N$, $I_n= I_N$?

Comment: You haven't defined $K_n$ and $I_n$. Your question is not clear...

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (a): Note that $K_n \subseteq K_{n+1}$ and $I_{n+1} \subseteq I_n$. What can you say about the dimensions if they are not equal?

Comment: If $L^N x = 0$, what is $L^N (L x)$?  If $y = L^N x$ for some $x$, what can you say about $Ly$?

Comment: If the characteristic polynomial of $L^N$ is $p(x) = x^m q(x)$ where $q(0) \ne 0$, then for any vector $y$, what can you say about $q(L^N) y$?

Comment: Where did you ues the fact if p∈R[x] is the characteristic polynomial of L , then p(L)=0 )? @Robert Israel